# Is there a Java library that implements one of the tests for the normality of a sample distribution?

Tags: java, statistics

I have a dataset and I want to test to see how close it is to a normal or gaussian distribution.  I know there are a variety of algorithms for doing this, eg. the Jarque-Bera test, the Anderson–Darling test and many others.

I'm hoping to find an open source Java implementation of one of these tests so that I don't need to implement it from scratch.  Can anyone offer any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistical library [SSJ](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/indexe.html):

1. Is licensed with GNU GPL
2. Is pure Java (no JNI)
3. Has [Anderson–Darling](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/probdist/AndersonDarlingDist.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://jdistlib.sourceforge.net/

this has many other normality test methods.